# Configuration file for assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, configuration

I have a configuration file for my Class Library assembly.

I know that it is wrong but it has to be like this.

When I build the Class Library project, the config file is copied to the output directory. However, when I build the entire solution, with the project where I'm using this library, it doesn't copy the `.dll.config` file to main project.

Maybe someone knows how can I force Visual Studio to copy the `.dll.config` to the main project where the assembly is executing?

Comment: completely lost, could not understand what you are talking about.

Answer (score 4):

To copy any file to output directory, you will need to edit file properties and set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

Comment: Same "flavor" of an solution, but I use Post-Build events in the csproj properties to copy "extra" config files.  App.Config and Web.Config are the only "automatics" I think.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you copy the .dll.config file to the output directory, it will still not be used by the application.

The only solution here is to merge the config settings from that file into your main projects config file.

You can think of the .dll.config files as nothing more than a collection of config settings that must be copied into the calling applications config file.  Kind of like a note being left to other developers that use that assembly in their projects.